# Spark is broadcasting large dataset not meant for broadcasting

Tags: apache-spark

I am using Spark 2.3.0, I have 2 datasets, both of them are reasonably large, 400 MB+. When I join these Spark tried broadcasting one of them. The one which has lesser no of columns (if it helps anyway identifying RCA). It fails with Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Futures timed out after [300 seconds] error as I've default settings for relevant configs.

I've default settings for spark.sql.broadcastTimeout and spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold (10 MB) I don;t want to disable broadcasting as much as possible.

While triaging I found that if I set broadcastTimeout > 60 it works, but it won;t work as dataset size increases. Not sure why spark is not honouring autoBroadcastJoinThreshold?

I am not using hive metastore, my files are stored on HDFS, I do use schema for them.

Tried adding dummy columns, as I believe in miracles :)

```
    Dataset<Row> MergedById = fromValidFromField.as("df1")
            .join(filteredByMailIds.as("df2"),
                    col("df1.id")
                            .equalTo(col("df2.id")),"inner")
```

This is the join that results in broadcast

Comment: also tried reducing threshold to just 4 MB, still same error, read around few articles that datafrfame size estimation issue may lead to this.

Answer (score 2):

Spark decides to broadcast, by estimating the size of data after the operations(like filter etc) on the dataset, not using the dataset's actual size.

For example: Let b(id: Int, name: String) be a table of size 1GB(> broadcast threshold).

```
select * from a join b ON a.id = b.id AND b.id < 100
```

In the above example, the Join strategy used will be **Broadcast**, since the data actually involved(assume 100 unique rows) in the join operation is very less and will be less than the default threshold of 10MB.

We can find the size of the data that is broadcasted by introspecting the plan.

```
Let plan: LogicalPlan = df.queryExecution.optimizedPlan
val size = df.find(_.isInstanceOf[org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.Join])
.get
.stats
.sizeInBytes
```

This should give hints of whether broadcast threshold is honoured.(The above codes assumes that there is one only join operation in the query)

Comment: Thanks @DaRkMaN for inputs. In this case I know for sure that threshold is not honored.  <br/> 
When I look at DAG->SQL, I see following for correponding query -  <br/>

BroadcastExchange data size (bytes): 419,430,400  <br/>
time to collect (ms): 4,447,967  <br/>
time to build (ms): 1,820  <br/>
time to broadcast (ms): 1,546  <br/>

Question is how do I fix this? And if Sparks decision is just based on what one may 
 <br/> call educated guess,  <br/>
but it still is a guess, isn't there any way to get out of this, apart from disabling it 
 <br/>

Comment: @bhushan, couple of questions. 
1. Is the side of the plan being broadcasted is a simple file read or involves a complex operation.    
2. Does the broadcasted side have compressed data? (The Join strategy is decided based on the size of the compressed data and does not take into account the compression factor if it were compressed) .  
3. Is it possible to compute stats for the table involve in join(so that Spark can make a better decision on the Join strategy) .      

Also, `org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution#stringWithStats`, give details of the plans stats.

Comment: following are numbered responses to your queries, thanks again. Response #1 Its not simple file read, after reading files there are join, filter, union etc operations involved. Following are actions that are happening with this join -

Comment: DS1 = load file (A)
DS2 = load file (b)
..some filters like not null, date based filter, 

DS3 = union DS1, DS2
DS4 = ...some computations on DS3 like few colunm transformations, filter, join, union
DS5 = ...some computations on DS4 like few colunm transformations, filter, join, union

... again some compuataions transformations, filter, join, union, legitimate explicit broadcast based filtering on both datasets, 
which leads to datasets DS6, DS7

Comment: and then the dataset doing broadcast
 Dataset<Row> MergedById = DS7.as("df1")
            .join(DS7.as("df2"),
                    col("df1.id")
                            .equalTo(col("df2.id")),"inner")

Comment: Response #2 I've not explicitly added any compression logic, apart from default offered by Spark via (spark.sql.inMemoryColumnarStorage.compressed, default=true), 
does that answer your question? Response #3
I am not using Hive meta store, my files reside on HDFS (no Hive) so I guess answer is no, I am not aware if there is any way compute stats without using Hive,
if there is, do let me know.

Comment: Following are queryexecution stats that you suggested to collect, logical plan clearly shows incorrect estimations, after following join operation - +- Join LeftOuter, (Fm#4 = filteredMailIdCol#173), Statistics(sizeInBytes=0.0 B, hints=none), corresponding statement in code is -   Dataset<Row> finalData = displayNameCorrected.join(mailidInternalList,
    displayNameCorrected.col(toCol).equalTo(mailidInternalList.col(mailFilteredMailId)), "left_outer");

Comment: Queryexecutionstat output is huge, stackoverflow won;t allow to post all. Any idea how can I share the stats?

Comment: One suggestion is to register the file scan dataframes as temp tables(`Dataset#registerTempTable`), and then run `analyze table <tblName> compute stats noscan`, and use the temp tables in your queries. The stats are propogated upwards through the plan, and all other node stats will get computed rightly.

Comment: Additional observation regarding the join I mentioned above. So one side of join has size of 200+MB and other side has just 89kb. May be that's why it is not estimating it correctly.

Comment: will try registerTempTable

Comment: Apologies for late response, but I am sort of in a spot now. I've not yet tried registerTempTable, however after running for second/third time after adding code for capturing queryexecution stats, the broadcasthash join is replaced by MergeSortJoin and error has gone, I've not made any other changes to code so trying o figure out what exactly happened

Comment: got busy in fixing the issue, it so happened that after re-engineering tasks, I managed to get rid of this join altogether, Thanks @DaRkMaN for all the help.